# DPDK distributor app and rte_prefetch_non_temporal() method

Tags: dpdk

What is the exact usage of rte_prefetch_non_temporal((void *)bufs[i + 3]); method and it's impact to the DPDK example distributor application. As of one of our integration we face "SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow with this point.

Once we commented out, it's start working.

Comment: We manage to fix it and solution will be post soon.it will help to community.